# Override Silent Mode

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to override the silent mode to make the phone broadcast a discreet sound or something similar. How can I do that in a simple way? I think I need to use AudioManager but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct you need to get the audio manager like so

```
AudioManager audioM = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

In order to override the silent mode use this

```
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Then play a discrete audio file like so

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourdiscretesound);
mp.start();
```

Or use the ringtone manager for a louder sound

```
int volume = audioM.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
audioM.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,volume,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);

theSound = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(pathtoyourringtone));

if(theSound!=null){
    theSound.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    theSound.play();
}
```

Related: Look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audiomanager.htm) for a tutorial on the AudioManager